# Can you connect to an Amazon RDS Instance by Database Name instead of hostname in Lambda Function?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-rds, serverless-framework

One of the things I like about DynamoDB is you can connect to it like so.

```
const params = {
      TableName: process.env.TWILIO_TABLE,
      Item: {
        callId: obj.CallSid,
        to: obj.To,
        from: obj.From,
        callerName: obj.CallerName,
        callerCity: obj.CallerCity,
        callStatus: obj.CallStatus,
        direction: obj.Direction,
        createdAt: new Date().getTime()
      }
    };
```

Note that all you need is the TableName and from your AWS credentials it knows what DynamoDB table you are referring.

**I want to connect to RDS in much the same way.**

I'm using the serverless framework to create the resource like below.

```
resources:
  Resources:
    uploadBucket:
       Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
       Properties:
         BucketName: ${self:custom.uploadBucket}
    RDSDatabase:
      Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
      Properties:
        Engine : mysql
        DBInstanceIdentifier: ${self:custom.databaseName}
        MasterUsername: Test123
        MasterUserPassword: TestPass123
        DBInstanceClass : db.m1.small
        AllocatedStorage: '5'
        PubliclyAccessible: true
      DeletionPolicy: Snapshot
```

Which in turn uses cloud formation to create the database instance for me.  In particular I am dynamically creating the database name and its identifier `DBInstanceIdentifier: ${self:custom.databaseName}`

That name changes based on the stage parameters (dev, beta, alpha, prod, etc...) that I use when deploying via serverless.

The idea is that a developer can automatically have a database created for him for testing purposes based on the stage if needed.  Say they created a custom stage like 'joe' for themselves to test with real resources before pushing to 'staging'.

The advantage of this is real testing and is easy to remove resources with `sls remove --stage joe` for example which removes all associated resources with that stage.

The problem is to connect to RDS you need to have the username, password and host.  These are located in the console after the resource is created but I need access to these somehow during my serverless script so I can set them to environment variables to easily connect to the correct databases for all my scripts.

So in short, the way DynamoDB works is perfect since I just reference the tableName and I don't have to worry about the hostname,username,password etc and it knows which tables are what.  **I need to do the same thing for RDS if possible or a workaround type solution.**

Any ideas?

Comment: One idea I have is since serverless will work with environment variables I can have a script that runs serverless for me but sets the environment variables automatically based on the RDS tables it finds accordingly using my own custom shell script.  This is one method possibly?

Comment: Something else that might help is a way to output the endpoint address to an environment variable perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is not exactly but I created a really nice workaround as long as you are okay with the database being publicly accessible.

Modify your resources file to something like this...

```
resources:
  Resources:
    uploadBucket:
       Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
       Properties:
         BucketName: ${self:custom.uploadBucket}
    RDSDatabase:
      Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
      Properties:
        Engine : mysql
        MasterUsername: ${env:RDS_USERNAME}
        MasterUserPassword: ${env:RDS_PASSWORD}
        DBInstanceClass : db.t2.micro
        AllocatedStorage: '5'
        PubliclyAccessible: true
        #TODO: The Value of Stage is also available as a TAG automatically which I may use to replace this manually being put here..
        Tags:
          -
            Key: "Name"
            Value: ${self:custom.databaseName}
      DeletionPolicy: Snapshot
    DNSRecordSet:
      Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
      Properties:
        HostedZoneName: yourdomain.com.
        Name: database-${self:custom.stage}.yourdomain.com
        Type: CNAME
        TTL: '300'
        ResourceRecords:
        - {"Fn::GetAtt": ["RDSDatabase","Endpoint.Address"]}
      DependsOn: RDSDatabase
```

My strategy here is to connect a Route53 record that takes the unique endpoint ID that is impossible to predict and make it a domain name you will understand.  In my case I create it with the stage name so my functions later will always know the database is located at database-dev.yourdomain.com

Using this you can now essentially know the HOST for all your lambda and or nodejs functions :).

Any better solutions to this are of course welcome, this is just what I came up with for now.